# Visual Studio Test Runner part of Express version (2013)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, visual-studio-2013

A very simple question imho that I cannot seem to find the answer for:

**Does Visual Studio 2013 Express come with the Visual Studio Test Runner?**

I am trying to get my build server to work with my unit tests but I get the error "TF900547: The directory containing the assemblies for the Visual Studio Test Runner is not valid" and this is why I consider installing Visual Studio on the build server. I do not want to waste a professional or ultimate license on the build server if possible.

Comment: The answer is NO.

Found answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020473/which-version-of-vs-should-i-install-to-allow-unit-testing-on-the-build-server?rq=1

Closing question.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but from my understanding, Express version lacks a lot of features which include something like extension.

So you probably have to rely on other tool such as NUnit Gui tool.

Comment: The question was - "Does Visual Studio 2013 Express come with the Visual Studio Test Runner?" I am not interested in Nunit.

Comment: maybe I am not been clear enough, I do not believe it has the test runner which other VS version have, and there is no easy way to integrate a test runner into Express version